# What request headers to use for uploading an image file from iOS to ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, objective-c, ios, asp.net-mvc, nsmutableurlrequest

I am building an iOS app where I want to upload images to an ASP.NET MVC server component like the posting of a file in a web page.

I have created the NSMutableURLRequest and NSConnection objects in iOS and have verified the call the the .NET server component is working.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setTimeoutInterval:(interval==0?SERVICE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL:interval)];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",SERVICE_BASEURL,url]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
...
```

The image data is in an NSData object from an AVFoundation module

```
NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
```

On the server the controller method in the .NET component is

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadMedia(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
{
 ...
  return Json(@"Success");
}
```

The goal is to transfer the image data to the server and store it. My questions are:

1. What other HttpHeaderField values need to be created?
2. How should I embed the image data in the NSMutableURLRequest?
3. What type should be parameter be in the .NET component method?
4. Based upon the type in #3 how should I extract the image data in the server component?

Comment: Turns out that unlike an HTML form file upload when the file comes from iOS in .NET the file is not automatically routed to the controller method as an instance of HttpPostedFileBase. You have to access it using the HttpContext.Request.Files property.

Comment: Didnt't you get this issue in .net? 
[InvalidOperationException]: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
I read somethings about it and even adding the keys 
aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys
aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers
keeps getting the same results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can post data use multi-part form-data.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                                   timeoutInterval:600];

request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSString *boundry = @"---------------AF7DAFCDEFAB809";
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:300 * 1024];

[data appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n\r\n", @"field name"]
                             dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[data appendData:imgdata];   // data upload
[data appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] 
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[data appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r--\n",boundry] 
                  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

request.HTTPBody = data;
```