# objective-c send image to .net soap webservice

Tags: objective-c, xcode, web-services, soap

I am trying to send images to soap webservice from an IPad. I couldnt succeed yet. I know that I have to send base64binary for image I dont how to get the image and convert it to that format. there are many tutorails but I dont understand them. they are all doing different things.

how can I simply send images with webservice? here is my code below

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<SendData xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "<containerId>%@</containerId>"
                         "<date_>%@</date_>"
                         "<image1>%@</image1>"
                         "<image2>%@</image2>"
                         "<image3>%@</image3>"
                         "<question1>%@</question1>"
                         "<question2>%@</question2>"
                         "<question3>%@</question3>"
                         "<question4>%@</question4>"
                         "<question5>%@</question5>"
                         "<question6>%@</question6>"
                         "<notes>%@</notes>"
                         "<transDate>%@</transDate>"
                         "<userId>%@</userId>"
                         "<macId>%@</macId>"
                         "<sFileID>%@</sFileID>"                             
                         "</SendData>"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n", @"33", @"2013-09-09", @"***image***1" ,@"***image***3" ,@"***image***3" ,@"true" ,@"true", @"true", @"true" , @"true" , @"3", @"notes", @"2013-09-09", @"123", @"mymacid", @"sfileid"];
```

do you have any suggestion?

I want to send it like I send a string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this [tutorial](http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2010/03/14/Convert-image-tofrom-text-%28Base64%29.aspx). This will convert image to base64.

This may help you.

Comment: the link is not opening

Comment: @coder you can try : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200880/what-request-headers-to-use-for-uploading-an-image-file-from-ios-to-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem. To solve expose your web services as REST services(JSON/XML). In my case i have created intermediary platform which will serve all my soap services as REST services. My iPhone application will send all my payload to Intermediary platform which in turn update the changes via web service calls. I have passed all the images as base64 string in my json payload to the intermediary platform.

Comment: but what is a good way to send the image? I can send the image now but it only sends center og the image :)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in my app. The size of the images taken from iPhone will be huge. So if you convert those images into base64 string will reduce you app performance. First reduce the image size by resizing the image.

```
     -(UIImage *) imageWithImage:(UIImage *) image scaledTOSize:(CGSize) newsize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newsize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newsize.width, newsize.height)];
    UIImage *newimag=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newimag;
}
```

After converting image into smaller or required size convert the UIImage into NSData

```
 NSData *imageData=[[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
```

Convert NSData into base64 string using below Third party library.
base64.h
NSData+Base64.h

```
NSstring *imageString=[imageData base64EncodedString];
imageString=[imageString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You can send the string to your services. Hope this will help you.